# Styling not parsed from backend

Tags: css, angular, text-styling

I have an application with an angular frontend and C# backend. 
I'm receiving this rich text from the backend of my application:

```
<b>Hello <span style="font-weight:normal"> world </span></b>
```

What gets displayed is " **Hello world** "
What I want to be displayed is " **Hello** world "

The desired behaviour is that the styling of the span doesn't get overwritten. This codepen example shows the desired behaviour, but it is frontend ONLY: 
https://codepen.io/david-lo/pen/rNVOEbY

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please try with this code <b>Hello <span style="font-weight:normal"> world </span></b> ?

Comment: @David Lo try like this `<p>"Hello <b> world</b>"</p>`

Comment: @AmanGojariya edited the question, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @DavidLo Your code is working on your codepen example.

Comment: @AmanGojariya Yes, the codepen shows how I want the outcome to be when i'm receiving the rich text from my backend (which does not work as intented).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue by using [SafeHtml](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/SafeHtml) and [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml) :

Before:

```
  public txt: string; //txt is rendered in my html file. 
  @Input() public set header(_txt: string) {
    this.txt = _txt;
  }
```

The string input `_txt` has value `<b>Hello <span style="font-weight:normal"> world </span></b>`

The problem was that my span styling was ignored so the output would be:

**Hello world**

After:

```
  public txt: SafeHtml;
  @Input() public set header(_txt: string) {
    this.txt= this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(_txt);
  }
```

By using DomSanitizer the way shown above, my span styling was respected in the frontend and I achieved the desired output:

**Hello** world

Answer (score 1):

Please Add below css

```
p {margin: auto; display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes my codepen example output appear on one line like: 
<b>Hello<\b> world. 
but this is not my main issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to render that code with the backslash symbols, this is clearly incorrect HTML.
The correct line should look like this:

```
<b>Hello <span style="font-weight:normal"> world </span></b>
```

Comment: The thing is that i'm sending it in kvotation marks from the backend, but it's received in the frontend the way that you're displaying it. I understand that that the question can be deceiving so i'll edit it.

Comment: Then I would suggest you inspect that specific element in the browser dev tools. Is the font-weight of the span overriden by a rule with "!important" flag? If no, check the font you are using - does it support different font-weights?